# problema con base de datos sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

hola estoy haciendo una projecto en blazor y cuando tratando de añadir en la base de datos recibio un error 500 sin embargo todos el camino es bueno de la vista al controlador

así el mensaje que recibio

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Movies' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

no sé de dondé eso viene

Comment: Sin ver el código que genera el error siempre es arriesgado formular una respuesta, Pero el error claramente dice que estás intentando insertar un valor en una columna donde no puedes hacerlo puesto que es identity, es decir auntoincremental. En la tabla Movies

Comment: Tal como dice Roger, sin el código es difícil elaborar una respuesta. Sin embargo ese error lo he visto al intentar insertar un valor arbitrario en un campo Identity o autonumérico.

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de insertar valores a Movies que es una Identity column como el error lo dice.

Puedes tratar de hablitar el identity insert en la tabla para poder ingresar los valores y ya luego volver a deshabilitar.

Seria algo como

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Movies ON
INSERT INTO Movies
/* Lo que insertes*/

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Movies OFF
```

Comment: Considero importante mencionar que aunque esta sugerencia funciona anula por completo la razón de ser de los campos Identity. En mi opinión esta lógica es util en un escenario de migración o copia masiva de datos donde sea importante conservar el valor de los campos Identity que contiene el origen.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos para las repuestas eso mi bien ayuda en final lo que hago es que borrar mi database y he rehace una migration y ahora funciona perfectemente.pienso que había un pequeno error al comienzo.